# Dialog-flow webhook Implementation

Tags: android, json, api, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I made a agent using dialog-flow API. Now i have to implement API in webhook for JSON response from server. i want to send dynamic parameter for getting the JSON response from server. Any tutorial will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this website explains very well how to create a Webhook using Node JS.: `https://chatbotslife.com/creating-a-nodejs-based-webhook-for-intelligent-bots-a91ecbe33402`